# When deploying to Azure: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'ON'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database

I have a web-application that returns the following error whenever I deploy it to Azure:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'ON'

It tells me the error comes from line 45 in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("LoginPartial", "Home")
```

Now, in the `HomeController` I have the following:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult LoginPartial()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var model = context.Users.Find(userId);

        // In case no such user is found and the model is called
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                FirstName = "N/A",
                LastName = "N/A"
            };
        }

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", model);
    }
```

...which works fine whenever I debug the application locally - even with databases remotely connected (they run from SQL Server in Azure).

My intention with this code is to display the FirstName and LastName of a logged-in user from a shared view (_LoginPartial.cshtml), and as I said it works fine locally - but crashes everytime I publish it to Azure.

If I comment out the two first lines within the LoginPartial() method, the problem disappears. But then again, so does the purpose with the method... So obviously there is a problem with accessing data from the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `context`, what is `.Users` and what is `.Find()`?

Comment: context is the database context where the AspNetUsers table is (ApplicationDbContext), .Users is for accessing the user-table in the database, and .Find() returns the ApplicationUser object with the given UserID. All this is part of Microsoft. AspNet.Identity and nothing I've written myself. I have debugged this section using breakpoints, and when running locally it retrieves the ApplicationUser object from the database context as expected.

Comment: What is your database provider (as configured in the entityFramework-section)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by entityFramework-section, but if you're talking about the web.config file, this is what it says: `<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />`
And in the connectionString: `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why it failed to run from Azure.

When deploying the solution along with the databases, I found out that User Instancing was not supported, and thus the databases were not successfully deployed.

By creating the database manually on the SQL Server and then selecting it from the "Publish Web"-wizard rather than attaching database files, the application is running from Azure without problems.

I also chose to "Execute Code First Migrations" for each database in the Publish Web wizard. Don't know if that has anything to do with it, but might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Though, I still don't understand why the application was able to run locally in debug mode, with the databases still on the very same SQL Server (not as local files).